# My 2DArray Structure won't work

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am supposed to get a output that should look like this:

0    1    2    3    4    5    6

1    2    3    4    5    6    7

2    3    4    5    6    7    8

But I keep getting 0s. What am I doing wrong? :(

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class gameStructure{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Environment();
    }
}


class Environment
{
    private int[][] table;

    Environment()
    {
        populate();
        output();
    }

    public void populate()
    {
        table = new int[3][7];

        for(int r=0;r<table.length;r++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<table[0].length;c++)
            table[r][c]=table[r][c];
        }
    }

    public void output()
    {
        out.println();
        for(int r=0;r<table.length;r++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<table[0].length;c++)
            out.println(String.format("%4d",table[r][c]) );
        }

        out.println();
        out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting `table[r][c]=table[r][c];` Are you sure you want to do that? Seems like you want to set it to `r+c`

Comment: Cool :-) I've added that as the answer if you want to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `table[r][c]` equal to `table[r][c]`. Seems like you want to do is set it to `r+c`:

```
public void populate()
{
    table = new int[3][7];

    for(int r=0;r<table.length;r++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<table[0].length;c++)
        table[r][c]=r+c;
    }

}
```